# You’ll tell me what you “learned”/“have learned"

Tags: difference, present-perfect, past-simple

For example, I lent my friend a book. Which one of these two sentences makes more sense to say?

> So you’ll tell me what you ***learned***.

> So you’ll me what you ***have learned***.

Comment: They're both fine. As usual, the Present Perfect *(**have** learned)* version implies *relevance to time of utterance*, so your first example is more about the "activity" of learning *in the past*, whereas the second one is essentially asking *What do you know **now** [as a result of having recently learned it]?*

Comment: Thank you so much..